# Find $E(|X-Y|^a)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are independent uniform on $(0,1)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

> Let $X,Y$ be independent $Uniform(0,1)$ random variables. Find $E(|X-Y|^a)$ where $a>0$.

My working:

> Define $W=1$ if $X>Y$ and $W=0$ if $X<Y$. We seek $E(|X-Y|^a)=E[E(|X-Y|^a|W)]=E(|X-Y|^a|W=1)P(W=1)+E(|X-Y|^a|W=0)P(W=0)=E((X-Y)^a)P(X>Y)+E((Y-X)^a)P(X<Y)$.
>
> Now $P(X<Y)=\dfrac{1}{2}$ and $P(X>Y)=\dfrac{1}{2}$ by symmetry.
>
> $E((X-Y)^a)=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x}(x-y)^af_{X,Y}(x,y)dydx=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x}(x-y)^adydx=\dfrac{1}{(a+1)(a+2)}$.
>
> Similarly $E((Y-X)^a)=\dfrac{1}{(a+1)(a+2)}$ by symmetry when $Y>X$.
>
> Required expectation=$\dfrac{1}{(a+1)(a+2)}\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{(a+1)(a+2)}\dfrac{1}{2}=\dfrac{1}{(a+1)(a+2)}$

But correct answer is $\dfrac{2}{(a+1)(a+2)}$.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Basically, you are confusing  $E((X-Y)^a;X>Y)$ and $E((X-Y)^a|X>Y)$. Note that the decomposition based on $W$ is not useful and that the first integral in the post corresponds to  $E((X-Y)^a;X>Y)$, neither to $E((X-Y)^a)$ (as written in the post), nor to $E((X-Y)^a|X>Y)$.

Answer (score 6):

You should have something like:
$$
E(|X-Y|^a)=\iint_{x>y}(x-y)^a\;dxdy+\iint_{y>x}(y-x)^a\;dxdy=2\iint_{x>y} (x-y)^a\;dxdy
$$
Now:
$$
\iint_{x>y}(x-y)^a\;dxdy=\int_{y=0}^1\int_{x=y}^1(x-y)^a\;dxdy=\frac{1}{(a+1)(a+2)} 
$$
So:
$$
E(|X-Y|^a)=2\iint_{x>y}(x-y)^a\;dxdy=\frac{2}{(a+1)(a+2)}
$$

Comment: "You should have at some point:
$E(|X-Y|^a)=E((X-Y)^a|X>Y)+E((Y-X)^a|Y>X)$" No they should not. And the integral afterwards is $E((X-Y)^a;X>Y)$, not $E((X-Y)^a|X>Y)$.

Comment: @Did, there seems to be a confusion :D But anyway, thanks. I also figured it out. I think this concept is now clear to me, having tried both the marginal and joint distribution cases.

Comment: The revised version is correct.